# Typescript/Angular - Creating a child array containing specific property of Parent JSON object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent object containing the following data

```
[
    {
        "BEGIN_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:36",
        "END_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:37",
        ...
    },
    {
        "BEGIN_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:37",
        "END_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:38",
        ...
    },
    {
        "BEGIN_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:38",
        "END_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:39",
        ...
    }
]
```

I want to create an **array** containing specific property of a parent object.
For instance, I need all values of END_TIME property. Something like following

```
child_array=parent_json.Get(END_TIME);
```

Expected result

```
["24 Feb 2023 13:37","24 Feb 2023 13:38","24 Feb 2023 13:39"]
```

Comment: If your requirement is not to have a specific method as `Get` on parent_json you can try `array.reduce((acc, current) => [...acc, current[key], [])` and the key could be any of the keys in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the map method:

```
const parent_json = [
  {
    "BEGIN_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:36",
    "END_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:37"
  },
  {
    "BEGIN_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:37",
    "END_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:38"
  },
  {
    "BEGIN_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:38",
    "END_TIME": "24 Feb 2023 13:39"
  }
];

const child_array = parent_json.map(obj => obj.END_TIME);
```